# Decrypting using a Caesar Cipher

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, encryption

I am working on a password saver and I have a Caesar Cipher for encrypting which is:

```
#  The encryption key for the Caesar Cipher
encryptionKey = 16

#  Caesar Cipher Encryption
def passwordEncrypt (unencryptedMessage, key):

#  We will start with an empty string as our encryptedMessage
encryptedMessage = ''

#  For each symbol in the unencryptedMessage we will add an encrypted symbol 
into the encryptedMessage
    for symbol in unencryptedMessage:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key

            if symbol.isupper():
                if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('A'):
                    num += 26
            elif symbol.islower():
                if num > ord('z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('a'):
                    num += 26

            encryptedMessage += chr(num)
        else:
            encryptedMessage += symbol

    return encryptedMessage
```

I have a predefined list of lists for testing purposes with two websites and their encrypted passwords:

```
passwords = [["yahoo","XqffoZeo"],["google","CoIushujSetu"]]
```

I give the user a series of choices and choice #2 lets the user lookup a saved password which is:

```
if choice == '2':  # Lookup a password
    print("Which website do you want to lookup the password for?")
    for keyvalue in passwords:
        print(keyvalue[0])
    passwordToLookup = input()
```

The password saver encrypts the passwords but I need it to decrypt the passwords using only the passwordEncrypt() function.

Comment: Was my answer deleted? I can't seem to find it anywhere and I'm almost certain I posted it.

Comment: To decrypt using your function, just pass the negative of `key`, for example `-16`